# How to drop pin and also get current location and coordinates from offline map tiles?

Tags: iphone

Please help me i want to get coordinate of droppin and also want to get current location in offline map tiles. how is it possible? please help me.

Comment: why minus point in this question? if you know then please tell me?

Comment: Those who are experts , they find this question silly so one of them may have decreased your marks.

Comment: if this is sully question then why no one can able to give answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wont get your current location in map offline using MKMapView. To do all your tasks use [cloudmade](http://developers.cloudmade.com/projects) map API.

Comment: nice find on cloudmade map API =)

Answer (score 0):

Implement this code...

```
-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mV viewForAnnotation:
(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {
MKPinAnnotationView *pinView = nil; 
if(annotation != mapView.userLocation) 
{
    static NSString *defaultPinID = @"com.invasivecode.pin";
    pinView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:defaultPinID];
    if ( pinView == nil ) pinView = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc]
                                      initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:defaultPinID] autorelease];

    pinView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed; 
    pinView.canShowCallout = YES;
    pinView.animatesDrop = YES;
} 
else {
    [mapView.userLocation setTitle:@"I am here"];
}
return pinView;
}
```

and for current location....as far as my knowledge, u can't get current location in simulator. so, one option is add .gpx file in ur project. You can add this by searching with .gpx. Set current location in that file, lat and lon. This is what I know. I have just done the same task...Good luck..:)

Comment: hello but i want to do this in offline map not in Mapview. i have map tiles and on tiles i want to drop pin.

Comment: you will need to elaborate more on your offline maptiles, and also the extent of internet connection, if mapview is not what you need, you will probably have to do the coordinate calculation on your own.

Answer (score 0):

This method will give you the coordinates of selected method and above method (mentioned by Goti ) is to put annotation at desired location.

```
 -(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)annotationView
    {   
        if([annotationView class]==[MKAnnotationView class])
        {
            CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = annotationView.annotation.coordinate;        
            NSLog(@"Latitude -> %f",coord.latitude);
                  NSLog(@"Longitude -> %f",coord.longitude);
        }
    }
```

Hope it will be helpful.

Comment: but i have offline map tiles not mapview.

Answer (score 0):

```
     MKMapView *locationMap = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,86, 320, 334)];
        [self.view addSubview:locationMap];
        locationMap.alpha = 1.0;
        locationMap.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
        locationMap.mapType = MKMapTypeStandard;
        locationMap.delegate = self;
        locationMap.showsUserLocation = YES;


- (MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>) annotation
{
    MKAnnotationView *a = [ [ MKAnnotationView alloc ] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"currentloc"];
    //  a.title = @"test";
    if ( a == nil )
        a = [ [ MKAnnotationView alloc ] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier: @"currentloc" ];

    NSLog(@"%f",a.annotation.coordinate.latitude);
    NSLog(@"%f",a.annotation.coordinate.longitude);

    CLLocation* currentLocationMap = [[[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:a.annotation.coordinate.latitude longitude:a.annotation.coordinate.longitude] autorelease];
    [self coordinatesToDMS:currentLocationMap];


    MKPinAnnotationView *annView=[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:a reuseIdentifier:@"currentloc"];
    if(a.annotation.coordinate.longitude == mapView.userLocation.coordinate.longitude ||  a.annotation.coordinate.latitude == mapView.userLocation.coordinate.latitude  )
    {
        if ([annotation isKindOfClass:MKUserLocation.class]) {
            //user location view is being requested,
            //return nil so it uses the default which is a blue dot...
            return nil;
        }       
        //a.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"userlocation.png"];
        //a.pinColor=;
    }
    else 
    {

        // annView.image =[UIImage imageNamed:@"map-pin.png"];
        //PinFirst=FALSE;
        //annView.pinColor = [UIColor redColor];
        // annView.annotation=annotation;
    }

    annView.animatesDrop = YES;
    annView.draggable = YES;

    annView.canShowCallout = YES;

    return annView;
}
```