# How to Drop multiple pin in offline map tiles and also get latl-long of that?

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a offline map tiles, i display it and also zoom in zoom out functionality in that and it's working very well, but now i want to drop multiple pins on offline map tiles and also want to get lat-long of that drop pin how it's possible ? please help me.

Comment: you have ask this type of question so many times . This is duplicate question of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9356548/how-to-drop-pin-and-also-get-current-location-and-coordinates-from-offline-map-t andhttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/9156131/how-to-drop-pin-in-offline-map

Comment: yes but still not get proper reply that's why i ask again may be i get some proper answer.

Comment: hey check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5067590/how-to-use-offline-cloudmade-maps-in-an-iphone-app may be help u

Comment: Thanks for reply, i checked it but now some data not found or removed from there.

Comment: r u sure that u will not get any help from my answer

Comment: yes because it was posted before to long time so now some data links are missing.

Comment: i see this code in this a offline map tile upload and when i click on map then i get lat and long. u will need this or not.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8850/discussion-between-dipen-chudasama-and-ios)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will get definitely solution form this link [Offline Maps iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5067590/how-to-use-offline-cloudmade-maps-in-an-iphone-app)

I have check and get lat and long when i click on map. so on click event u will drop a pin.

in this link u will see the answer which is given by Ruben Esposito.

MAy be it help.